# CurrentPage alias - Umbraco

Tags: xslt, umbraco

I have the following problem. My node tree looks like this:

- Home

  - News Area

    - News1
    - News2
  - Events Area

    - Event1
    - Event2

When you want to display it on the main site, everything is fine.

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/eventsArea/simpleEvent [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
```

However, this only works to find on the main page of my site. When I go to a subpage, this solution does not work anymore.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

So I assume you want to display a list of events on every page, like on a sidebar.
To do so, instead of starting at `$currentPage` start at `/root/home` like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/home/eventsArea/simpleEvent [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
```

or if you want to find all simpleEvent pages regardless of where they exist do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//simpleEvent [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
```

The latter will keep working if someone changes the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the first and the second does not work.

If the code looks like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$currentPage/eventsArea/simpleEvent [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
<xsl:sort select="@createDate" order="descending" />
<xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $numberOfItems">
<a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}"><xsl:value-of select="@nodeName"/></a>
<p><xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:TruncateString(umbraco.library:StripHtml(bodyText), number($excerptLength), '...')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></p>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It all works as it should.

[image]

```
<xsl:for-each select="/root/home/eventsArea/simpleEvent [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
```

or

```
<xsl:for-each select="//simpleEvent [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']">
```

Do not display anything.

[image]